# SQLAlchemy Filtering Not Working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying to use a filter on a query, but for some reason the filtering does not seem to be working.  For example, if I run the command:

```
Curriculum_Version.query.filter(Course.course_code == 'PIP-001').all()
```

I get the same results as if I run:

```
Curriculum_Version.query.filter(Course.course_code == 'FEWD-001').all()
```

(Both return):

```
[#1 Version Number: 1, Date Implemented: 2013-07-23 00:00:00, #2 Version Number: 2, Date Implemented: 2013-07-24 00:00:00]
```

If I run:

```
Curriculum_Version.query.get(1).course
```

I get:

```
from main import app, db
from flask import Flask, request, g, redirect, url_for
from flaskext.auth import Auth, AuthUser, login_required, get_current_user_data
from flaskext.auth.models.sa import get_user_class
import datetime
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pdb


class User(db.Model, AuthUser):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tf_login = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)  # can assume is an email
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    salt = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role = db.Column(db.String(80))  # for later when have different permission types
    zoho_contactid = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    created_asof = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, zoho_contactid, firstname, lastname, tf_login, password, role, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(tf_login=tf_login, password=password, *args, **kwargs)
        if (password is not None) and (not self.id):
            self.created_asof = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            # Initialize and encrypt password before first save.
            self.set_and_encrypt_password(password)
        self.zoho_contactid = zoho_contactid  # TODO
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.tf_login = tf_login  # TODO -- change to tf_login
        self.role = role

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#%d tf_login: %s, First Name: %s Last Name: %s created_asof %s' % (self.id, self.tf_login, self.firstname, self.lastname, self.created_asof)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'tf_login': self.tf_login,
            'firstname': self.firstname,
            'lastname': self.lastname,
            'role': self.role,
            'created_asof': self.created_asof,
        }

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return o.id == self.id

    @classmethod
    def load_current_user(cls, apply_timeout=True):
        data = get_current_user_data(apply_timeout)
        if not data:
            return None
        return cls.query.filter(cls.email == data['email']).one()


class Enrollment(db.Model, AuthUser):
    __tablename__ = 'enrollments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='enrollments')
    curriculum_version_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('curriculum_versions.id'))
    curriculumversion = db.relationship('Curriculum_Version', backref='enrollments')
    cohort_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cohorts.id'))
    cohort = db.relationship('Cohort', backref='enrollments')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#%d User ID: %s Version ID: %s, Cohort ID: %s' % (self.id, self.user_id, self.curriculum_version_id, self.cohort_id)


class Cohort(db.Model, AuthUser):
    __tablename__ = 'cohorts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id'))
    course = db.relationship('Course', backref='cohorts')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#%d Start Date: %s, Course: %s' % (self.id, self.start_date, self.course.course_code)


class Curriculum_Version(db.Model, AuthUser):
    __tablename__ = 'curriculum_versions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    version_number = db.Column(db.String(6))
    date_implemented = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id'))
    course = db.relationship('Course', backref='curriculum_versions')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#%d Version Number: %s, Date Implemented: %s' % (self.id, self.version_number, self.date_implemented)


class Course(db.Model, AuthUser):
    __tablename__ = 'courses'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    course_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
    course_name = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '#%d Course Code: %s, Course Name: %s' % (self.id, self.course_code, self.course_name)

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return o.id == self.id
```

How I'm Creating the Entry in the DB for Curriculum_Versions:

```
def update_courses():
    course_code = request.form['course_code']
    start_date = request.form['start_date']
    course_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    curr_version = Curriculum_Version.query.filter(Course.course_code == course_code) \
        .order_by(desc('version_number')).first()

    if curr_version is None:
        next_version = 1
    else:
        next_version = int(curr_version.version_number)+1

    existing = Curriculum_Version.query.filter(Course.course_code == course_code) \
        .filter(Curriculum_Version.date_implemented == course_date)

    if len(existing.all()) > 0:
        return "You tried to make version %d of the curriculum, but version \
        %s of the curriculum already exists for %s for class %s." \
        %(next_version, existing.first().version_number, start_date, course_code)

    course_object = Course.query.filter(Course.course_code == course_code).first()

    if course_object is None:
        return "The course %s does not yet exist!" % (course_code)

    new_version = Curriculum_Version(version_number=next_version, date_implemented=course_date, course=course_object)
    db.session.add(new_version)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Created version %d for course %s starting on %s.' \
            %(next_version, course_code, start_date)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to join before you filter and use just one query:

```
# Get all the versions of a single course.
versions = Curriculum_Version.query.join(Curriculum_Version.course).filter(
    Course.course_code == "PIP-001").all()
```

Otherwise sqlalchemy will not know to use the relationship before filtering.

If you just specify a filter then sqlalchemy does not know to perform a join and you end up with sql similar to this:

```
SELECT curriculum_versions.* FROM curriculum_versions, courses WHERE 
    courses.course_code = "PIP-001"
```

Which does not make a whole lot of sense but is valid SQL.  When you use a join it leverages the filter against the correct table like this:

```
SELECT curriculum_versions.* FROM curriculum_versions JOIN courses ON
    curriculum_versions.course_id = courses.id WHERE courses.course_code = "PIP-001"
```

Note that sqlalchemy knows to use the condition `curriculum_versions.course_id = courses.id`
because you pass in `Curriculum_Version.course` to `query.join()` and you specified that relationship on your `Curriculum_Version` class as the course property and it automatically knows to use the only foreign key available between the `curriculum_versions` and `courses` tables (which you also had to specify on the `curriculum_versions.course_id` column).

You can read more about joins here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have a sec, can you explain more why you need the join and how it defines the relationship?

Comment: I tried to expand the explanation as far as I understand it, hope it helps.  You might try printing out the queries and viewing the SQL because it is crucial in determining if you are giving SQLAlchemy enough information to do the "right thing". You can print the query objects explicitly before calling `first()` or `all()` or you can also turn on sqlalchemy's echo flag to have all queries logged.

Answer (score 3):

You can query as follows:

```
course_id = Course.query.filter(course_code="PIP-001").first().id
curriculum = Curriculum_Version.query.filter(course_id=course_id).all()
```

Comment: I'm still getting Curriculum Versions that are not associated with the course with the code "PIP-001" when I run it this way :(.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your foreign key for "Curriculum_Version" saving correctly?

Comment: @codegeek: +1, but the first line should end with `first().id` instead of `first().course_id`.

Comment: Miguel - Even with that fix, I'm still getting the exact same results no matter what the course_id is.

@NickWoodhams - I thought I was saving the foreign key correctly.  I updated the original question with how I'm creating the DB entry.  Any ideas why it may not be working?

Comment: In Curriculum_Version class, you have course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id')). Shouldn't it be course.id and not courses.id ?

Comment: I had courses because it is the tablename ("__tablename__='courses'") for the Course class.  Should it not reference the tablename but the actual classname instead?

Comment: When I change it to Course.id, I get the error "NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Curriculum_Version.course - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression."

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this demo app I've put together. It's a single page Flask & SQLAlchemy app, and I think it describes everything you should need:

https://github.com/Thinkful/sqlalchemy-demo